# Code reading: why is the following code implemented like this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

I'm looking over the code for [group_cache_key](https://github.com/saturnflyer/group_cache_key/blob/master/lib/group_cache_key.rb) method, and I've never seen this way of writing before:

```
require 'activerecord'
require 'activesupport'
require 'digest/md5'

ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval {
  Array.class_eval {
    def cache_key
      if self.empty?
        'empty/' + self.object_id.to_s
      else
        ids_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.collect{|item| item.id }.to_s)
        update_timestamp = max {|a,b| a.updated_at <=> b.updated_at }.updated_at.to_i.to_s
        create_timestamp = max {|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }.created_at.to_i.to_s
        self.first.class.to_s.tableize+'/'+length.to_s+'-'+ids_hash+'-'+create_timestamp+'-'+update_timestamp
      end
    end
  }
}
```

Why is the method implemented like that? What's the point of having a `class_eval` inside a `class_eval`, and defining `cache_key` on Array?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the method is to add caching for arrays of records besides for standard caching on individual records, and so it was implemented within `Array`.  Most likely, the author was trying not to pollute the ruby `Array` class by wrapping it inside a class_eval of `ActiveRecord::Base`.  This approach won't prevent this pollution, but it will add the `cache_key` method that was desired.

Comment: So, will this apply to an `ActiveRecord::Relation` as well?

Comment: @Tempus, this code was written in 2009 for Rails 2.3.x before `ActiveRecord::Relation` (a Rails 3.x concept) existed.  And no, it will not apply to other collections (unless they are subclasses of Array).

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to use `class_eval` instead of just reopening the class would be to fail fast in the scenario where the class doesn't exist. This isn't possible in the code you've shown, since ActiveRecord is being required. I would guess the author just had a weird stylistic preference.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping this would only change `Array` in the context of `ActiveRecord`.

So I created a small test-program to verify that:

```
class Test
  class Array
    def initialize(bla)
      @array = bla
    end
  end

  def self.get_array_of(something)
    Array.new([something])
  end
end

Test.class_eval {
  Array.class_eval {
    def to_s
      "BLAAAAAAAA"
    end
  }
}

puts ["a", "b", "c"].to_s
puts Test.get_array_of("b").to_s
```

unfortunately the output of this program indicates only the global `Array` is affected, and the `Test::Array` only has the default `to_s` function. Bummer.

So the only reason I can then think off to do it this way, is because this will raise if `ActiveRecord` does not exist.

Comment: Good point about checking for ActiveRecord, although there are more straightforward ways to do the same thing (e.g. `defined?`).